# Unable to run Internet explorer 7 on Wine 1.2

Tags: wine, internet-explorer-7, ubuntu-8.04

Following the instructions from [here](http://www.wine-reviews.net/wine-reviews/applications/ie-7-on-linux-with-wine.html).

I installed IE7. But when I run it with Wine 1.2 with:

```
wine iexplore.exe &
```

I get:

```
Explorer$ fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x5b9f97, 0x6f4b08, {3e1fd72a-c323-4574-9917-5ce9c936f78c}, 1, 0x32f414, (null), (null), 0x6f4b10,)
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x5b9f97, 0x6f4b28, {afff9c82-5be3-4205-9b3e-49e014c09a63}, 1, 0x32f414, (null), (null), 0x6f4b30,)
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x6cd15f38, 0x6cd20180, {e2821408-c59d-418f-ad3f-aa4e792aeb79}, 1, 0x32f260, (null), (null), 0x6cd20188,)
fixme:process:RegisterApplicationRestart (L"-restart /WERRESTART",0)
err:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken Unhandled Token Information class 18!
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),2,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsA (0x5e00187b, 0x5e0155f8, {1fb3f43f-4827-46e5-89e2-b398580357a3}, 1, 0x32da50, (null), (null), 0x5e015600,)
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsA (0x5e00187b, 0x5e015618, {7c0334a1-4635-4d95-8d76-9cf3171ac618}, 1, 0x32da50, (null), (null), 0x5e015620,)
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0050069c
fixme:msimtf:DllGetClassObject ({50d5107a-d278-4871-8989-f4ceaaf59cfc} {00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} 0x32dfb4)
err:ole:apartment_getclassobject DllGetClassObject returned error 0x80040111
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {50d5107a-d278-4871-8989-f4ceaaf59cfc} could be created for context 0x401
fixme:urlmon:ZoneMgrImpl_GetIESecurityState (0x143f20)->(1, 0x32c4b4, (nil), 0) stub
fixme:urlmon:SecManagerImpl_ProcessUrlAction Unsupported arguments
fixme:shdocvw:IEParseDisplayNameWithBCW stub: 0x0 L"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=74005" 0x14d030 0x32d560
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032dd20
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032db18
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {807c1e6c-1d00-453f-b920-b61bb7cdd997} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {807c1e6c-1d00-453f-b920-b61bb7cdd997} could be created for context 0x1
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
fixme:urlmon:SecManagerImpl_ProcessUrlAction Unsupported arguments
fixme:shdocvw:IEParseDisplayNameWithBCW stub: 0x0 L"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=74005" 0x131468 0x158d2f4
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032de7c
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032dc74
fixme:urlmon:Uri_IsEqual (0x165ae8)->(0x165210 0x32c164)
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d6dc
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d4d4
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d6dc
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d4d4
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=004a796c
fixme:toolbar:TOOLBAR_CheckStyle [0x10122] TBSTYLE_REGISTERDROP not implemented
fixme:toolbar:TOOLBAR_CheckStyle [0x10122] TBSTYLE_REGISTERDROP not implemented
fixme:toolbar:TOOLBAR_Unkwn45D hwnd=0x10122, wParam=0x00000000, size.cx=1280, size.cy=1020 stub!
fixme:toolbar:TOOLBAR_CheckStyle [0x10122] TBSTYLE_REGISTERDROP not implemented
fixme:wininet:InternetSetOptionW Option INTERNET_OPTION_RESET_URLCACHE_SESSION: STUB
fixme:urlmon:Uri_GetScheme (0x1728a8)->(0x32e310)
fixme:urlmon:Uri_GetScheme (0x18e400)->(0x32e310)
fixme:shell:SignalFileOpen (0x00000000):stub.
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x158e808, 0x158e408, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x158e808): stub
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0x32d098, 0x32cc98, 1024, 0x0): stub
fixme:rpc:NdrStubCall2 new correlation description not implemented
fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0x32d098): stub
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d02c
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032ce24
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d52c
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d324
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
fixme:shdocvw:IEParseDisplayNameWithBCW stub: 0x0 L"http://google.ca/" 0x197e00 0x17fe9e4
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d48c
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d284
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d52c
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d324
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d4d4
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d2cc
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d52c
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d324
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=005a2b88
err:comboex:COMBOEX_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d4d4
err:toolbar:ToolbarWindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=0032d2cc
err:rebar:REBAR_WindowProc unknown msg 200b wp=00000000 lp=
```

And I am unable to open any webpages. How can I fix this?

Comment: i recommend you to install playonlinux and from that you will get a good gui to install all softwares or games.....try to install like that..playonlinux tries to install custom wine versions to help program work according to needs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the information is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Installed PlayOnLinux which runs Wine 1.3.6 and got IE7 with using POL. The IE7 Security levels had to be adjusted considerably to use Active X controls on a web page e.g. to download the latest Flash player from Adobe, had to temporarily lower the security levels to risky.

Also, doing a manual installation of IE7 on Wine without PlayOnLinux, you can just use winetricks and you don't need to do all the extra instructions in the link above. Winetricks options here:
http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at ***[IEs4Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEs4Linux)***.
It saved me so many times (bank account checking, web development - for testing...)

Here's a detailed instruction on how to install & run it under Ubuntu :)

http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Installation:Ubuntu

Currently the development status is *inactive*, since the latest stable version was released in 2008.

Comment: Link is dead and the provided information is outdated.

Comment: Most likely. I answered in 2012. No need for negative votes :)

Comment: Btw. Wasn't me, these down-votes are few years old as well.

Comment: No problem, just saying :)